# Premature optimization is the...cure of all CPU timeouts?

Tags: apex, governorlimits, loop, cpulimit, performance

[According to Donald Knuth](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) actually "is the root of all evil". 
But this doesn't seem to hold true on the Force.com platform and its CPU time Limit.

After watching Paul Battisson's [Faster Loops](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-edHmVGMkU0) [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xVLWMGM-cBU) it seems we should NOT care about readable, short Apex code but have to add complexity and weird optimizations to get enough done inside the limits.

The platform seems not to optimize the code in ways e.g. the Java compiler does it.

But why aren't there official Apex best practices by Salesforce.com itself in the way: Optimize here or there?!

**Whom would I turn to to find out where my code could be (dramatically) optimized?**

Comment: FWIW, I'm working on some benchmarks. Some results are rather ... surprising.

Comment: In [the summer 15 release notes](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_apex_expressions_coverage.htm?edition=&impact=) it mentions that static string concatenation is optimized. It would be useful to know what other optimizations are occurring.

Comment: Usually it's applying the right algorithm that makes the big difference e.g. loop and map vs loop inside loop. Apex executes in the JVM so gets a lot of the same speed ups that Java does. (But classes like StringBuilder are missing.)

Comment: @KeithC we reach a CPU Timeouts only at a single customer where our managed code has complex (multi level triggers code called on many records. The additional time consumed by customer org WFRules, Formulas, Rollups adds up to more than 10s. Without a full log (reach the 2M much to early) I see no way to profile this.

Comment: Yeah painful. Support can up the log size and turn on detailed logging for your managed package code so you can figure out what is happening. In my code the problem has usually been hidden exponential cost code. For example, a method called per object and then a layer or two down another per object loop.

Comment: @RobertSösemann Have you used the Developer Console Profiling features (switch your perspective to "Analysis" then look under "Execution Overview" > "Timeline" for a start)? I've found this to be quite helpful in determining what parts of the execution (Apex, Workflow, Validation, etc.) are taking up the most relative time, and from there which sections of Apex are the most time consuming. Doesn't always mean there's much you can do to change it, though :)

Comment: @zachelrath yes i know that useful view but the max log size hides the interesting parts in its lags ;-)

Comment: @RobertSösemann If you drill down in the performance tree you can get down to the particular methods / lines of code that are consuming the most time --- no need to look in the logs. But I agree, the max log size makes debug logs virtually useless for performance testing.

Comment: In regards of faster for loops, what is it with Apex implementation that they haven't fixed it? Paul's method looks like desugared regular for loop, so what is limiting Salesforce to sugar it properly so that there was no performance penalty?

Comment: Someone just pointed me at this - appreciate it is old but just wanted to add some context. I don't think readability should come at the expense of performance, more if you are working with a large data set in a loop or doing something like a batch  job then the "faster" method would be better. I would also argue that the faster method is not that much less readable (its a standard for loop from all languages) but agree it is less "sugared" than the alternatives.

Comment: @pbattisson your opinion is always appreciated. But my point is not readability vs. speed but the fact that the guys who build the compiler need to optimize begin the scenes. Every good language must be used for understandability by humans and expressiveness